# Connecting MSSQL to PHP 5.5 on Centos 6

Tags: sql-server, pdo, odbc, centos6, php-5.5

I want to connect **`mssql`** in my site and it's  on **CENTOS 6** and I am using **PHP 5.5**.

Got many solutions online about installing drivers regarding the **PDO** and **ODBC**, always getting error of no package found or failed dependencies, don't know why I am not able to install or proceed further.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If You want to use mssql_connect, You need to install php-mssql from extras repository:

```
yum install --enablerepo=extras php-mssql
```

and restart httpd:
service httpd restart

That's it  :-)

Comment: Thanks @ravi ! I am aware of this command but I'm not able to get the repository which works with this.I already mention this that I'm getting error if I am using something like this. Can you suggest me the repo for the above?

Comment: Well for that, you could try 
 edit your /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo file and enable the “extras” section, and then run
----------------------------- OR ---------------------------
yum-config-manager --enable extras

Comment: If you want to use mssql_connect, go back in time. It doesn't exist in the last two versions of PHP. Use something modern!